# How do I install devDependencies of a package in bower?

Tags: bower

If I do a fresh install of a package (for example Polymer, but it could be _anything):

```
merc@mercs-thinkpad:~$ mkdir tt
merc@mercs-thinkpad:~$ cd tt
merc@mercs-thinkpad:~/tt$ bower install polymer
bower cached        https://github.com/Polymer/polymer.git#1.6.0
bower validate      1.6.0 against https://github.com/Polymer/polymer.git#*
bower cached        https://github.com/Polymer/webcomponentsjs.git#0.7.22
bower validate      0.7.22 against https://github.com/Polymer/webcomponentsjs.git#^0.7.20
bower install       polymer#1.6.0
bower install       webcomponentsjs#0.7.22

polymer#1.6.0 bower_components/polymer
└── webcomponentsjs#0.7.22

webcomponentsjs#0.7.22 bower_components/webcomponentsjs
merc@mercs-thinkpad:~/tt$
```

The devDependencies are missing from the tree:

```
merc@mercs-thinkpad:~/tt$ ls -l bower_components/
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 merc merc 4096 Jul 16 21:37 polymer
drwxrwxr-x 2 merc merc 4096 Jul 16 21:37 webcomponentsjs
merc@mercs-thinkpad:~/tt$
```

However Polymer has clearly a devDependency:

```
merc@mercs-thinkpad:~/tt$ cat bower_components/polymer/bower.json 
...
  "dependencies": {
    "webcomponentsjs": "^0.7.20"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "web-component-tester": "*"
  },
```

The bower page says:

```
merc@mercs-thinkpad:~/tt$ bower help install

Usage:

    bower install [<options>]
    bower install <endpoint> [<endpoint> ..] [<options>]

Options:

    -F, --force-latest      Force latest version on conflict
    -f, --force             If dependencies are installed, it reinstalls all installed components. It also forces installation even when there are non-bower directories with the same name in the components directory. Also bypasses the cache and overwrites to the cache anyway.
    -h, --help              Show this help message
    -p, --production        Do not install project devDependencies
    -S, --save              Save installed packages into the project's bower.json dependencies
    -D, --save-dev          Save installed packages into the project's bower.json devDependencies
    -E, --save-exact        Configure installed packages with an exact version rather than semver
    Additionally all global options listed in 'bower help' are available

Description:

    Installs the project dependencies or a specific set of endpoints.
    Endpoints can have multiple forms:
    - <source>
    - <source>#<target>
    - <name>=<source>#<target>

    Where:
    - <source> is a package URL, physical location or registry name
    - <target> is a valid range, commit, branch, etc.
    - <name> is the name it should have locally.
```

Which seems to imply that devDependencies are ALWAYS installed, except for when you specify otherwise.

However, I can't seem to find a way to *actually* install devDependencies using bower for *any* package.

What am I missing?

Comment: What were you missing?